# SSH/ Telnet PAM configuration

Tags: ssh, pam, telnet

How do I configure maximum number of login attempts before the session is dropped for SSH/telnet in PAM?

Comment: Just an aside, one sentence *"how do I [x]"* questions aren't very popular on ServerFault. That's what Google is for.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `faillog`:

```
-m, --maximum MAX
           Set the maximum number of login failures after the account is disabled to MAX
```

So `faillog -m 5 -u user` should allow the user `user` 5 tries to enter his password correctly.

The following will lock the user account after `X` tries.
Add this to your PAM config and change according to your wishes:

```
auth required pam_tally.so onerr=fail deny=3
account required pam_tally.so reset
```

BTW, I [googled it](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-security-4/pam-pam_tally-and-locking-out-users-after-3-failed-login-attempts-in-rhel5-624257/).

*edit*: got it wrong the first time.

Comment: pam_cracklib.so doesnt serve the purpose. My requirement is to configure maximum login attempts when the password prompts while login, not while changing the password.
Please note

Comment: I've updated my answer. Check if that works for you now.